# Why UIViewController's view's coordinate is (0,20) and how to change (iPad)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I find that UIViewController's view's coordinate is (0,20),size is 1024*748 in MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard ,and I can't change.How can I change view to (0,0) and size is 1024*768 ,so I can show the view full sceen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Due to status bar of size 20 present on the top.
In the storyboard you could go to attributes inspector and change Status bar to none.
Which will show full view of size (1024, 768)which can be helpful for setting view by storyboard.
And than in view controller's .m file write below method :

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];
}
```

Comment: You may also want to set the "status bar hidden" property in your plist in case your app never shows the status bar. There's also a "wants full screen layout" checkbox on view or window, I forget where it is exactly.

Answer (score 1):

That is probably because of the status bar. You can hide the status bar as such `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES];`